# elasticsearch java query match any of my list

Tags: java, list, elasticsearch, filter

I am trying to build a query with java which filters all hits by a list.
Let's say I have a list of different names and now i want to build a query which returns all elements with the names stored in my list. 
Since there are going to be 100+ names in this list i just want to pass the whole list to my query.

First I tried to build a raw query in my elasticsearch head plugin to make it easier for me to implement it into java.

At the moment my raw query looks like this:

```
{
"query": {
   "bool": {
      "filter": {
          "term": {
             "name": {
                "value": [
                   "name1",
                   "name2"
                ]
              }
           }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I know that i have at least one element with the name "name1", same for "name2". But this query doesn't return anything. 
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Asiemie

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `term` query does not support arrays of values.  However the `terms` one does so you can do the following:

```
{
"query": {
   "bool": {
      "filter": {
          "terms": {
             "name": [
                   "name1",
                   "name2"
                ]
           }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html

You can also wrap term queries into a `bool` -> `should` query like so:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "term": {
                "name": "name1"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "name": "name2"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: wow, this little letter "s" just made my query work. Thanks a lot! Your second solution won't work for me since i dont want to add 100+ conditions. But for smaller ones it would, thanks! :)